# reduction of parameter list causing duplicate code

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm working on an ATM machine project and I frequently need to pass bill amounts as parameters to functions. There are many functions that look similar to

```
depositCash(int fives, int tens, int twenties, int fifties){...}
```

I know that it's bad practice to have a function with too many parameters such as 4. So I tried to bundle these parameters in a new class billBundle and pass that as a parameter instead. But then I ran into a new problem of repeatedly having to write duplicate code like the following:

```
Billbundle billBundle = new BillBundle();
billBundle.setFives(fives);
billBundle.setTens(tens);
billBundle.setTwenties(twenties);
billBundle.setFifties(fifties);
depositCash(billBundle);
```

And if i just passed all the bills to bill bundle then that would be doing exactly what I was trying to avoid in the first place. How should I handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Well whadaya know.... I didn't realize ATM Machines counted money being deposited. Never seen it before. I always thought you just throw the money into a supplied envelope, slip it into the ATM when asked for it, then God sorts out the mess afterwords. I suppose however there are banks with trust issues towards their members. Use an Integer Array, element 0 is the number of 5's, element 1 is the number of 10's, element 2 is the number of 20's....and so on. A $335.00 deposit: 1,1,1,4,1 or 1,3,0,0,3 or ....

Comment: I don't think _four_ parameters can fairly be called "too many". So if your original 4-param version of `depositCash` was working out well for you, I'd say just go with it.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll just keep it like that for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BillBundle` idea looks fine to me.  You say you had to repeatedly write code like this:

```
Billbundle billBundle = new BillBundle();
billBundle.setFives(fives);
billBundle.setTens(tens);
billBundle.setTwenties(twenties);
billBundle.setFifties(fifties);
depositCash(billBundle);
```

But did you *really* or are you just thinking that you might?

A `BillBundle` like this should only really be made when the bills are *counted*, and I'd be surprised if that happens in more than a couple places.

Code that doesn't actually change or determine the number of each bill should just pass the bill bundle around.  The method that logs how many bills of each kind were deposited?  Pass it the `BillBundle` you got from counting.  The method that adds up the total amount of money?  Pass it the `BillBundle` you got from counting. etc. etc.

This is far better than passing around 4 parameters all over the place for two reasons:

1. Far fewer opportunities to mess things up -- every function that takes 4 bill params and passes them elsewhere has a chance to pass them in the wrong order or in the wrong parameter positions.  This is especially problematic since the actual counts are all the same type (i.e. `int`), and lots of arguments use that type for completely different things.
2. Far less code is actually dependent on the kinds of bills you support.  Lets say your country switches to a $5 coin, or you just don't want them in the machines anymore... how much code has to change to get rid of fives? You'll need to change the code that counts bills and all the other stuff that actually cares about the amounts of each bill, but you shouldn't have to change any of the code that just passes those counts around.  They can just pass around the original `BillBundle` and don't have to worry about it.

One change I would suggest is making your BillBundle immutable.  Then you don't have to worry about anyone changing it as you pass it around.

Something like:

```
class BillBundle
{
    public final int fives;
    public final int tens;
    public final int twenties;
    public final int fifties;

    public BillBundle(int fives, int tens, int twenties, int fifties)
    {
       this.fives = fives;
       this.tens = tens;
       this.twenties = twenties;
       this.fifties = fifties;
    }
}
```

I'll warn you that most Java programmers would prefer getter methods instead of public final fields, but there is no good reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

`BillBundle` as a parameter object is a scalable approach to reduce the parameter list of the methods. As any implementation of [parameter object design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object) implies also moving around the code handling the parameters. An option to avoid the code duplicates for getting the bills and pass them to methods like `depositCash` could be a mix between the [visitor design pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-visitor-pattern) to get the bills and [template method design pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-template-method-pattern) to process them

Assuming the information used to compute the bills comes from ATM a bill emitter could compute the bills and accept as visitor a bill processor which gets the bills and process them

```
interface BillEmitter {

    int getFives();

    int getTens();

    int getTwenties();

    int getFifties();

    default void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

// add BillEmitter implementations as needed

public class SomeBillEmitter implements BillEmitter {

    private Atm atm;

    public SomeBillEmitter(Atm atm) {
        this.atm = atm;
    }

    public int getFives() {
        int theFivesBill = 0;
        // compute the fives bill with the information from ATM
        return theFivesBill;
    }

    public int getTens() {
        int theTensBill = 0;
        // compute the tens bill with the information from ATM
        return theTensBill;
    }

    public int getTwenties() {
        int theTwentiesBill = 0;
        // compute the twenties bill with the information from ATM
        return theTwentiesBill;
    }

    public int getFifties() {
        int theFiftiesBill = 0;
        // compute the fifties bill with the information from ATM
        return theFiftiesBill;
    }
}
```

The visitors

```
interface Visitor {

    default void visit(BillEmitter billEmitter) {

        // template method which gets the bills from the billEmitter
        // and pass them to the bill processor

        Billbundle billBundle = new BillBundle();
        billBundle.setFives(billEmitter.getFives());
        billBundle.setTens(billEmitter.getTens());
        billBundle.setTwenties(billEmitter.getTwenties());
        billBundle.setFifties(billEmitter.getFifties());

        processBills(billBundle);
    }

    void processBills(BillBundle billBundle);
}

// add Visitor implementations as needed

public class DepositCashVisitor implements Visitor {

    public void processBills(BillBundle billBundle) {
        // deposit the cash
        ...
    }
}
```

The usage

```
public class Atm {
    // add methods which returns information used to emit bills
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Visitor depositCashVisitor = new DepositCashVisitor();

        Atm atm = new Atm();
        BillEmitter billEmitter = new SomeBillEmitter(atm);
        billEmitter.accept(depositCashVisitor);

        // add more bill emitters and visit them with depositCashVisitor
        // or add more visitors and visit billEmitter with them
    }
}
```